# Is there a $_ (entire line, complete line) special variable in Hadoop Pig Latin?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to filter out lines in an incoming data set if ANY variable contains, say, a non-printable character.

The problem is that I don't want to have a regexp match for each column, would just like to regexp match the entire line, like `$_` in PERL. Something that would go along with `$0`, `$1`, etc. Or perhaps a `$*` to mean any column (unsure what would happen to the numeric column).

Thus, I would like to do something like this:

```
tuple_stuff = LOAD 'really_big_file' USING PigStorage()
    AS (
      some_column:LONG,
      another_column:CHARARRAY,
      yet_another:CHARARRAY
      ...
      ninty_fifth_column:CHARARRAY);

filtered_stuff = FILTER tuple_stuff BY ! $_ MATCHES '[^:print:]+';
```

(side note: I can't remember of Pig matches the entire string or just anywhere in the string...thus, do I need the "+" extender?)

Being required to use a JAVA UDF is fine, provided I don't have to install anything goofy.

Note: I realize the obvious limitations of this: once loaded in, the original line would most certainly not be available. Thus, it might have to be some form of modifier in LOAD.

Comment: Have you tried loading the data as a line:chararray and then using the expression on the line.

    tuple_stuff = LOAD 'really_big_file'  AS (line:chararray);
    filtered_stuff = FILTER tuple_stuff BY ! line MATCHES '[^:print:]+';

Comment: Oooh, going to try that. THanks!

Comment: by the way, turns out PIG uses the java weirdness (\p{Print})